# Sleep not activating

Tags: autohotkey

This script allows me to toggle the spam of the 1 key. While it does work, Sleep does not seem to activate. This is copied code.
Can anyone explain to me why?

```
$1::
  KeyWait, 1
  While !GetKeyState("1","P")
   Send 1,
   Sleep 100,
  KeyWait, 1
Return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$1::
  KeyWait, 1
  While !(GetKeyState("1","P"))
  {
    Send, 1
    Sleep, 100
  }
  KeyWait, 1
Return
```